# setting up ssl on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, devise

I'd like to require ssl authentication for the user resource on devise. I was expecting that to be as simple as it is in rails, like:

```
  devise_for :users, :constraints => { :protocol => "https" }
```

Also, I couldn't find any documentation on devise's github, though I've found some dead links pointing to it at the google groups.

Does anybody has a hint on how to get it working easily? I thought I'd be simple, given the popularity of the plugin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

:constraints won't work as option, but this probably will:

```
constraints :protocol => "https" do
  devise_for :users
end
```

Comment: I changed my devise to use this and it didn't work. I got `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"`

Comment: I had a problem with signing out too, so here's an answer that could help others. Basically, the problem was that `DELETE "/sign-out"` (with http) was redirected to `GET "/sign-out" (https)`. So I replaced my `sign_out_path` by `sign_out_url(protocol: "https")`, and now it works fine. I actually overrode sign_out_url to always set the protocol.

Answer (score 7):

[Integrate SSL Requirement](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29) into your app and using Devise.  The answer didn't work but this did for me, especially since I was using SSL Requirement already.

Comment: You are right, I didn't check the answer correctly back then, and didn't update here. Did you get the redirection between ssl routes and regular routes to work?

Comment: I had mine working before, but now you are scaring me... I literally just implemented it but started coding somewhere else.  I can check. gulp...

Comment: The article linked to worked for my Rails 3 app using: config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.ssl_required :new, :create } in my application.rb file.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Rack::SSL](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2010/11/29/ssl-with-rails/), maybe with [Rack::SslEnforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer) for more configuration options.